# Deserialize xml xmpp message to object

Tags: c#, xml, xmpp, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a xml string to a c# object. This is the message:

```
<message from='test1@localhost' to='test2@localhost'><result xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp' id='A6QV1I4TKO81'><forwarded xmlns='urn:xmpp:forward:0'><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='test1@localhost' stamp='2015-07-21T09:12:09Z'></delay><message type='mchat'><subject/><body/></message></forwarded></result></message>
```

And this is the class

```
public class Delay {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="from")]
    public string From { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="stamp")]
    public string Stamp { get; set; }
}

public class Active {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}

public class XmppMessage {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="body")]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="lang")]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="to")]
    public string To { get; set; }
}

public class Forwarded {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="delay")]
    public Delay Delay { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="message")]
    public XmppMessage Message { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}

public class Result {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="forwarded")]
    public Forwarded Forwarded { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="message")]
public class MessageHistory {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="result")]
    public Result Result { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="from")]
    public string From { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="to")]
    public string To { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code to deserialise:

```
MessageHistory messageNode;             
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MessageHistory));
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(message))
                    {
                        messageNode = (MessageHistory)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
                    }
```

The object property "from" and "to" are fine but the "Result" is returning null. I can't understand what I'm missing here...

Comment: Add [XmlRoot(ElementName="..")] to all the classes.  The name is case sensitive so you have your class name "Forwarded" and the tag name "forwarded".  Adding the XmlRoot  will allow the tag to be lower case and the class name to be upppercase.

Comment: the XmlRoot on the MessageHistory class was enough, the problem was the namespaces...thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the namespaces in the XML. you have to specify the namespaces explicitly, like this:

```
public class Forwarded
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "delay", Namespace = "urn:xmpp:delay")]
    public Delay Delay { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "message")]
    public XmppMessage Message { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "forwarded", Namespace = "urn:xmpp:forward:0")]
    public Forwarded Forwarded { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "message")]
public class MessageHistory
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "result", Namespace = "urn:xmpp:mam:tmp")]
    public Result Result { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "from")]
    public string From { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "to")]
    public string To { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it's working now! Thank you very much! I had no idea that the namespaces were required :/